# Native interop types constructors must not be called directly

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I trying use `NSRange` in code

```kotlin
actual class PlatformRegex actual constructor() {

    actual fun findAll(pattern: String, input: String): List<String> {
        val regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern = pattern, options = 2, error = null)

        val range = NSRange(rawPtr = NativePtr.NULL).apply {
            location = 0u
            length = input.length.toULong()
        }
        val matches = regex.matchesInString(string = input, options = 2, range = range.readValue())
        return matches.map { match -> match.toString() }
    }
}
```

But have error in PhaseScriptExecution:

```
PlatformRegex.kt: (14, 21): Native interop types constructors must not be called directly
(14 line for me in "val range = NSRange...")
```

Answer (score 0):

`val range = NSMakeRange(loc = 0, len = input.length.toULong())`